# convert text html to svg text

Tags: html, svg

[we have a json that can have a text in the following ways]

```
  text{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text: ['I am a single line text']
    }
```

[suppose the text is 150px automatically when we insert it in the div the text is 150px but the size It is 50px the text automatically makes its line breaks even if they do not exist.]

[What's up in svg? The existing line breaks are read and although line breaks are visually seen if they don't exist, it doesn't take them into account]

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1519138?key=bcd96756ccf017b35edfd61e87197e82

[the text on the left is html and the text on the right is svg text]
[I have no problem interpreting the enter or the line breaks but I do]
[In the html it does not have it I can not do what solution could apply to that problem]

Comment: SVG has no native line break capability. If you want them you'll need to write something in javascript to implement it.

Comment: You may try to put the text inside a `<foreignObject>`